# Getting a warning I don't understand when trying to useradd with m & d options

Tags: users, useradd

I'm trying to add a new user, "abc", with a home directory of "/test/abc", for him, using the useradd command on an Ubuntu machine as follows:

`useradd abc -md /test/abc`

and everything works out fine with the new user "abc" & his home directory of "/test/abc" being created.
However, I keep getting the following error:

```
 useradd: warning: chown on `/test/abc' failed: No such file or directory
```

which I don't understand.

Why is there a `chown` command being performed?

And why did the error state that there's no such directory, "/test/abc", when there obviously is one that's being created after I ran the `useradd` command?

Comment: I think this is what happens (man useradd): *"-d, --home-dir HOME_DIR
           The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
           user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
           BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
           HOME_DIR does not have to exist **but will not be created if it is
           missing**."*

Answer (score 1):

If your `/test` directory was not created before executing the `useradd` command, it will not create the entire path (both `/test` and `/test/abc`), it will only create the `/test/abc` folder if `/test` already exists.

As a fast way, remove the user:

```
sudo userdel -r abc
```

Ensure your `/test` dir is there

```
sudo mkdir -p /test
```

then you can

```
sudo useradd abc -md /test/abc
```

You don't have to do `chown`, as it will automatically create the `/test/abc` folder with user `abc` and group `abc`.